# Question about reduction mod p method for polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am a undergradute math student and I was traying to prove the polynomial $p(x)= x^4-10x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. I used reduction mod p and for every prime p I found a factorizarion in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. I know $p(x)$ is irreducible, but i have a question about this method. If I try with many primes and anyone works, i have to try until I find one that works? or try with another method.Thanks for any comments.

Comment: No, it never works for any prime here with the reduction criterion, but it is well known that the polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$. See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875878/proving-that-x4-10x2-1-is-not-irreducible-over-mathbbz-p-for-any-pr) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204279/show-that-x4-10x21-is-irreducible-over-mathbbq?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Yes, but i have another question. If i have a polynomial p(x) and I try with reduction mod p, and if i try with p=2, and does not work, the i try with p=3, and does not work again, it could be posible that it works for p = 53,  for example? Or, if with p=2,3 does not work, is recommendable try with other primes or just change the method?

Comment: Yes, this can happen. We have many posts here as examples. See, say, [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3150309/irreducibility-of-x5-10x455x3-110x2184x-60-in-mathbbqx?rq=1). The polynomial is reducible modulo $p$ for $p=2,3,5,7$, but then irreducible for $p=11$.